# How to change variable value if condition is met in filter operator at RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following code that will not subscribe and therefore will not execute setDischarges method if condition in filter (!!discharges && !!discharges.length) is met.

```
loading: boolean;

this.discharge$ = this.dischargeService.getObservable('discharges');
    this.subDischarge = this.discharge$
      .pipe(
        filter((discharges: Discharge[]) => !!discharges && !!discharges.length),
        map((discharges: Discharge[]) => discharges),
      )
      .subscribe((discharges) => this.setDischarges(discharges));
```

I would like to change the loading variable value if that condition is met in filter. However, I tried the following code and it is not working, because when that condition is not met it does not subscribe and therefore cannot execute setDischarges. I need to change the loading variable value if that condition is met and if that condition is not met, but not affecting the subscription when the condition is not met.

```
loading: boolean;

this.discharge$ = this.dischargeService.getObservable('discharges');
    this.subDischarge = this.discharge$
      .pipe(
        filter((discharges: Discharge[]) => !!discharges && !!discharges.length 
        ? this.loading = false : this.loading = true),
        map((discharges: Discharge[]) => discharges),
      )
      .subscribe((discharges) => this.setDischarges(discharges));
```

Comment: Maybe just add a tap after the filter and set the loading variable in that?

Comment: @R.Richards The problem is that the subscription fires twice. First time it returns an empty array and the second time it returns the array with the data. If I add tap, it will set loading to false in the first return and then it will change again in the second return. It will work if I really don't have data, because the second return will never fire. I think I would need something that will get the first return and second return and give me both in one subscription.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.subDischarge = this.discharge$
      .subscribe((discharges) => {
        this.loading = discharges && discharges.length;
        this.setDischarges(discharges);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of clarity in you question so I'm assuming that **dischargeService** is a service call to and **getObservable** returns an observable containing the content of your API request. Similar to you AJAX calls in JavaScript every API call in angular is asynchronous i.e. your code or logic to set you loading boolean should on only be executed when you get the response from your service call.

The way to do this is to subscribe to your observable. To do this you can user the subscribe function which will catch the response from your service call. So the code you will end up is as follows

```
this.loading = true;
this.dischargeSub = this.dischargeService.getObservable('discharges').subscribe(discharges => {
   // This will only be executed on successful response
   this.loading = false;
   this.setDischarges(discharges);
}, err => {
   // Error block to handle your error case
});
```

The variable **dischargeSub** will store an instance of the subscription which can use to unsubscribe when there is new service call to the API or on destroy of the component

Comment: I have no problem subscribing to it and getting the data. That's not the question.

Comment: @crthc Why do you want to filter the data to change the value of a global variable. A filter is used to filter an array of elements based on some condition. What you are doing there does not require a filter.

Comment: I am not filtering the data to change the value of a global variable. I wanted to change the value of the global variable if that condition is met just there.

Comment: This code will achieve the same without any fuss, please try it

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. However, just realized the problem is that the subscription fires twice. First time it returns an empty array and the second time it returns the array with the data. So, it will set loading to false in the first return and it will change again to true in the second return. This solution will work if I really don't have data, because the second return will never fire. I think I'd need something that will get the first return and second return and give me both in one subscription, therefore I can change the loading variable after it finishes the two fires or just one.

Comment: @crthc made a small edit based on my understanding of your requirement